# Datagridview Cell Style in C#: unable to get exactly the same font size

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have sent the font of my datagridview called 'dgr_Operations' to Calibri size 9.

When my user form is loaded I call the method createDataGridStyles described below.

```
    private void Frm_Dialog_Solde_Comptes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     try
     {
      createDataGridStyles();
      this.CenterToScreen();
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     {
        ClsErrorManager.manageException(exc);
     }

     finally
     {
     }
    }
    private void createDataGridStyles()
    {
        try
        {            
            this.m_DataGridViewCellStyleIntro = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            this.m_DataGridViewCellStyleIntro.Font = new Font(this.dgr_Operations.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            this.m_DataGridViewCellStyleIntro.ForeColor = Color.Blue;                               
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ClsErrorManager.manageException(exc);
        }

        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

When I try to apply the style, the cell does not seem to be formatted in Calibri 9 :

```
for (int m = 0; m < this.dgr_Operations.Rows.Count; m++)
            {
                l_CellValue1 = this.dgr_Operations[0, m].Value.ToString();

                switch (l_CellValue1)
                {
                    case "EN":
                        // this.dgr_Operations[1, m].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                        // this.dgr_Operations[1, m].Style.Font.Bold = FontStyle.Bold;
                        this.dgr_Operations[1, m].Style = m_DataGridViewCellStyleIntro;
                        break;
 // [...]
```

Do you have an idea what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Where do you call `createDataGridStyles()` ?

Comment: I call it in my Form_load

Comment: Did you debug and check `this.dgr_Operations.Font` is `Calibri` and `9` ?

Comment: yes, I did. It was indeed Calibri - 9.

Comment: Use Microsoft Word and write the two lines in there in Calibri 9, and bold one of the lines.  It's not going to look much different.  The color doesn't bold very well for that font.

Comment: Thanks - but the difference in Word is clearly visible

Comment: Not on my computer.  My test matches your grid output.

Comment: Thanks - I made a trial with Calibri 10 and it looks indeed that the bold is not rendered very well.